# Parent Window Closing when Closing Child Window

Tags: java, swing, window, parent-child

I have an application that creates a new window (let's call it Cuprins) when a button of the same name is pressed. The problem I have is that when I close the new window, it also closes the main one. Is there anyway to make the main window not close when closing the Cuprins window?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)   (But see also `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis/7143398#7143398) for the immediate 'fix'.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check what's the default close operation. Set it to "dispose on close" or "do nothing on close"

Answer (score 1):

The newly opened window should use dispose on close to dispose the frame, or setVisible(false) to hide it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line while you creating child window.

```
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Usage example :

```
AddLeagues addLeague = new AddLeagues(); //Child View
addLeague.setVisible(true);
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```